# NSNumber doubleValue method returns null in objective C (IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumber

I am doing some iOS learning and I have an NSNumber which appears to be in order but when I ask for the doubleValue of it, I get null.

```
[stack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]]
id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
if([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    NSLog(@"%@",topOfStack);
    NSLog(@"%@",[topOfStack class]);
    result  = [topOfStack doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

This prints:

```
2012-04-11 17:52:04.909 RPNCalc[4127:f803] 3
2012-04-11 17:52:04.910 RPNCalc[4127:f803] __NSCFNumber
2012-04-11 17:52:04.910 RPNCalc[4127:f803] (null)
```

Why would the doubleValue come out as null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting NULL because %@ is the string literal for an object.  Doubles are not objects.  Use %f to NSLog a float or double.

Answer (score 2):

Replace NSLog(@"%@",topOfStack); with NSLog(@"%g",topOfStack);

Comment: @CodaFi Apple's NSString format specifiers match IEEE's printf ones, so %f, %e, %E, %g, and %G all work (but print slightly differently)

Comment: I think you mean `NSLog(@"%@",result)`